# How do I calculate Z axis in CSS?

Tags: html, css, parallax

My goal is to have everything back to it's original size using scale() after a z axis is applied.

I have a wrapper with an arbitrary perspective:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}
```

Then I will have layers eg:

```
.layer_00 {
  transform: translateZ(-20px) scale(???); /* Farthest away and slowest */
}
.layer_01 {
  transform: translateZ(12px) scale(???); /* On top and quick */
}
.layer_02 {
  transform: translateZ(3px) scale(???); /* In between and medium pace */
}
```

I really suck at math but would like to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the following seems to work.

```
(perspective - translateZ) / perspective = scale
```

But if they're positioned via `translateX` and `translateY` then they'll need to be multiplied by the scale.